# Url break issue

Tags: url

I had a bibliography item with `url` that breaks in two line. The break is fine but the box is too wide on the right which there is empty space in the box.

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\special{papersize=8.5in,11in}

% Packages Section
%=================
\usepackage{amssymb}            % Complex numbers
\usepackage{bbding}             % Symbols
\usepackage{bm}                 % Bold Math
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[pdftex,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames, pdftex]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Support for french language
\usepackage{wordlike}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,positioning}

% Set up Section
%===============

% Page configuration
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}

% Remove the header line
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% Setup subsection format
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}

% Setup enumeration
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi})}

% Paragraph configuration
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

% Listing configuration
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.75}

\newcommand{\me}[1]{\mathrm{\emph{e}}^{#1}}
\newcommand{\jcplx}[0]{\mathrm{\emph{j}}}

% Setup listings
\lstset {
    language=Matlab,
    frame=single,
    backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray},
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{blue!40!black},
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{green!40!black},
    identifierstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    showstringspaces=false,
    captionpos=t
}

% Text Section
%=============
\begin{document}
    \begin{thebibliography}{9}
        \bibitem{svm}
        Analytics Vidhya : Understanding Support Vector Machine algorithm
        from examples (along with examples),
        \\\url{https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/09/understaing-support-vector-machine-example-code/}
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Which gives the following:

[image]

Is that any way how to make the box stop write just after the `url` text?

Comment: In my opinion that box looks horrendous. I always use `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` to make it disappear, or `\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}` to paint the text instead.

Comment: Off-topic: The bib entry example you've provided is seriously incomplete, as it's missing information about both the author (Sunil Ray) and the publication date (last updated Sept. 2017). The "author" of this piece is *definitely not* an entity called "Analytics Vidhya".

Comment: If you use `wordlike` for emulating poor typesetting, you shouldn’t worry about that break. 

Answer (score 4):

Your code has a lot of errors I corrected in the following MWE. Important is for exampe the order of calls of packages. In your case that means `hyperref` should be called last.

I deleted all packages not needed for your problem, but left packages with wrong options to correct them. Please read my comments carefully, marked with `<=====`.

Your font package `txfonts` should not be used any more.  See for the reasons [the infos on ctan](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/newtx). Use `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` instead of `\usepackage{txfonts}` (Mentioned in a comment of @Mico).

The way the box is ending is hardcoded in `hyperref`. IMHO it is better to use option `colorlinks` for `hyperref`, now the complete text of the link is colored. With for example option `urlcolor=blue` you can define the used color for url links ...

I would not use `\\` to get the url string to a new line. 
To get a better-looking bibliography, I would use package `ragged2e` with command `\RaggedRight`.

With the complete MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\special{papersize=8.5in,11in} % <========================= changed to:
\usepackage[total={8.5in,11in},centering,margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Support for french language
\usepackage[french]{babel}

%\usepackage{txfonts}  % 'txfonts' is deprecated; use newtxtext and newtxmath 
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{ragged2e} % <====================== for command \RaggedRight
\usepackage{parskip} % <===================================== instead of 
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% Page configuration
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
% Remove the header line
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{graphicx} % <================================ pdftex deleted
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor} % <============ pdftex deleted

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[%
  colorlinks, % <=======================================================
  urlcolor=blue,
]{hyperref} % <=============== 'pdftex' and 'breaklinks' options deleted



% Text Section
%=============

\begin{document}

{% start bibliography group
\RaggedRight
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
  \bibitem{svm}
    Analytics Vidhya: Understanding Support Vector Machine algorithm
    from examples (along with examples),
%   \\ % <==============================================================
    \url{https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/09/understaing-support-vector-machine-example-code/}
\end{thebibliography}
} % end bibliography group
\end{document}
```

results in the following pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: +1. One more document aspect you could point out as being deprecated is the use of the `txfonts` package. Better to load the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages.

Comment: @Mico Thanks, I added your comment to my question ...